# Querying Firestore Database for Date Range

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm building an app to help people carpool from the airport and I'm trying to query my database for rides within a certain range.

Here is what I have:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class DiscoverRideViewController: UIViewController {

    var userFullName = String()
    var dateEarly = Constants.UserInfo.chosenDate.addingTimeInterval(-900)
    var offset = TimeInterval()

    @IBOutlet weak var createRide: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(dateEarly)
        offset = TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
        print("timezone offset: ", offset)
        dateEarly = dateEarly.addingTimeInterval(offset)

        print("searching for documents:")
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("rides-wfu").whereField("aiport", isEqualTo: Constants.UserInfo.chosenAirport).whereField("ridetime", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: dateEarly).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func newRideTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        print(Constants.UserInfo.chosenDate)
        db.collection("rides-wfu").addDocument(data: ["airport":Constants.UserInfo.chosenAirport, "ridetime":Constants.UserInfo.chosenDate, "groupmembers":[Constants.UserInfo.firstName+" "+Constants.UserInfo.lastName, "", "", ""]])
    }
}
```

The create ride function is successful, but I am having trouble querying, and yes, I have built an index. I've tried just about everything and db.collection().where() methods are creating errors on my compiler for some reason -- only whereField() methods are working. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

[Constants class:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNI2W.png)
My constants class seems to be working it is how I am sharing variables between view controllers.

[This is the error I receive when I try to use 'where' instead of 'whereField', although from the documentation it looks like 'where' is a valid command for querying the Firestore database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqM0.png)
Could it be that I need to download any additional pods? The ones I have are:
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

Comment: "creating errors on my compiler for some reason" If you're getting an error, please include the exact error message and the stack trace (or the line that causes the compiler error) in your question.

Comment: I agree with the above comment - far too vague a description of the issue. You can help us to help you by clarifying *what* the errors actually are and giving us enough code to understand the issue. For example we don't know what `Constants` is - if it's nil, then the code will crash. I am not seeing anything fundamentally wrong with the code so please update it before it's closed so we can try to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks so much for your response. I have updated the post to include more relevant information. Let me know if there are any other pieces of info you would like to know in order to help

Comment: @Jay Thanks so much for your response. I have updated the post to include more relevant information. Let me know if there are any other pieces of info you would like to know in order to help

Comment: Answer below. Note that the query causing the problem is now only in a screenshot. Including a screenshot if text is seldom useful. In the future: 1) make sure the [minimal code that actually causes the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is in your question, 2) include it as text, which is the most reusable format. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text (for Firestore structures, image is ok) so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. If you include an image, please include it in the question, not a link. Over time, links can break and if they do, future readers wont have access to that info which could invalidate the question.

Comment: I believe you have a typo as you're creating a field *airport* `data: ["airport"` but you're querying for a field *aiport* `.whereField("aiport"`

Comment: Good catch on the type Jay!

Answer (score 1):

You now have this as a query:

```
db.collection("rides-wfu").where("ridetime", ">", timestampEarly)
```

This is not a valid query syntax for Swift. What you're looking for is:

```
db.collection("rides-wfu").whereField("ridetime", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timestampEarly)
```

I highly recommend studying the Firebase documentation on [querying Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), as that contains examples of this and many more types of queries.

Comment: If you look at the original code I literally already had the exact line of code you suggested included and it does not return the timestamps that are greater than or equal to the ridetime. I have been pouring over the documentation but came here because I was having issues. Thank you for your response

Comment: @MatthewLewis The problem is the contents of the question don't match what the issue now is. The original question states (and showing via a screenshot) that your *db.collection().where() methods are creating errors on my compiler*. `.where` is not valid syntax whereas `.whereField` is. So it's the correct solution to *that* question. Now, if you're query is not returning the correct results, that's a totally separate issue from what's posted. You now state *it does not return the timestamps*. So, accept this answer because it's correct, and then post a *separate* question with the new issue.

Comment: To address this followup comment from the OP, there's a code typo in the question. See my comment; aiport vs airport.

Comment: @Jay Thanks so much, the typo fixed everything. Sorry for creating this wild goose chase and thanks again for your help